# Combine several independent git repositories under one root folder

Tags: git, github, configuration-management

I want to combine several thematically related but otherwise independent repos under one root folder, while at the same time keeping their histories seperate.

The end result should look like this

```
root
   >repo1
      >.git
      >...
   >repo2
      >.git
      >...
```

or this.

```
root
   >.git
   >repo1
      >.git
      >...
   >repo2
      >.git
      >...
```

where I want to be able to download or clone the root collection from github and get exactly that structure locally.

I prefer the first solution - but is it feasible and how?

Comment: One problem i see with option 2 is that if you commit to repo1 or repo2, you will have to commit to root each and every time as well....

Comment: Asking `Which is the best` is strictly off-topic, as it tends to attract opinionated answers, not based on factual reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with submodules as described in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules. This would be the second approach. I would recommend this option to you.

If you want the first option, you need to write a script, that generates this kind of structure. You cannot push the first solution to github as the root folder is not a git repository.